# Track GPS route two way on Android

Tags: android, gps, tracking

I am developing a GPS based app which records the route I traveled. Basically start position and destination is captured and drawn the route on Google map. But the issue is, If I traveled from A-B and return to A again. I could not track the point where i turn and the Google direction api does not takes three locations to draw the route. How can i track this A-B again to A position.Please help me to over come to this issue. Many thanks.

Comment: you can draw A to B then B to C then C to D where D is back again to your starting point

Comment: Can you post a sample or tutorial where i can get an idea about to implement it.

Comment: I am drawrng it as you suggested. But the D position i some how closed to A position in other way route. So the google direction api polygone response between those two locations not A-B-C-D-A. Because I am sending the direction request with A and D positions.

Comment: `a GPS based app which records the route I traveled. Basically start position and destination is captured ` ??? I would not call that 'recording the route' when only two points are recorded.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.